# combinatorics shelf arrangement

Tags: combinatorics

Any help with this problem would b highly appreciated.

Brian needs to put twelve distinguishable school books away. Four of them are science, five are math and the remaining three are computer books. How many ways can Brian arrange the books if:
 (a) All books are to be placed on a single shelf in any order?
           I know this one is 12!

(b) All books of the same subject must be grouped together, all on one shelf?

(c) Each book can be placed on any of three different shelves in any order?

(d) All books of the same subject must be grouped together on a separate shelf, but each
subject may be placed on any of the three shelves?

(e) Each subject is on a different shelf and the books within each subject are arranged in alphabetical order?

I'm assuming for this one the books can each only be arranged in one way so that would just leave the arranging on the shelves which I think is P(3,2). I have an answer key for these problems but I don't know how to arrive to the answers of b,c,d, and e(I got the right answer but I'm not sure if the approach is correct).

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:  For b, first choose the order of the subjects, then the number of ways to order each subject.  For c, put the books in order on the first shelf, then pick the last (some number) to move down to the second shelf, then pick the last (some number) to move down to the third shelf.  This is a stars-and-bars problem.

For b, imagine piling each subject into a pile.  There are three piles.  Take the books in each pile and put them in order, which you can do in $3!, 4!, \text{ and } 5!$ ways.  Then you can put the subjects in order in $3!$ ways, so the total is $3!4!5!3!$

For c, you have $12!$ ways to order the books, just as in a.  Now you need to have some of them on the first shelf, so imaging putting a divider where you shift from the first shelf to the second shelf and another divider where you shift from the second to the third.  The two dividers can go together if there are no books on one shelf.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) has a good discussion of the last factor.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately I don't really see it the way you do and I'm still struggling to understand what exactly it is you mean. Thank you for your time though

Comment: Thank you so very much. That really really helped me. Once again, thank you.

Comment: Did you get d?  Your answer to e is correct.

Comment: Yes I did! Thanks again Ross!